# What is the nature of the interference patterns inside the ice?

Tags: optics, interference, ice

Recently saw some interesting optical effects inside/under the ice on the frozen pool which I never noticed before. Looks pretty much like thin-film interference patterns to me. A quick search did not yield any relevant results, so I'm looking for an explanation for these optical patterns.

[image]